# 8th order particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, computational-complexity, homogeneous-equation

[image]

I am given that $r^7 - 6r^6 + 20r^5 - 56r^4 + 112r^3 - 160r^2 + 192r - 128 = (r-2)^3(r^2+4)^2$.

Then I know that the characteristic equation is then $r*(r-2)^3(r^2+4)^2 = 0$

This gives me $r = 0,2,2,2,+2i,-2i,+2i,-2i$

So I know the complimentary solution will be $y(t) = c_1 + c_2e^{2t} + c_3te^{2t} + c_4t^2e^{2t} + c_5\cos(2t) + c_6 \sin(2t) + c_7t\cos(2t) + c_8t\sin(2t)$.

However, what can I assume for my Y(t) for the particular solution?

Is $Ate^{2t} + Bt + C\sin(4t) + D\cos(4t)$ a good guess for $Y(t)$?

Are there more efficient ways of computing $Y^{(8)}(t)$ without a brute force approach of having to compute eight consecutive derivatives?

Thank You

Comment: Note that the RHS contains $t^\color{red}{3} e^{2t}$.

Comment: I guess you are missing the fact that the exponential is multiplied by $t^3$ and not by $t$ only. And as far as I remember this is important for the choose of the particular solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R.H.S. consists of a polynomial, a trigonometric function and a product of an exponential with a cube. Respectively

$$t^3\cdot e^{2t} + t + \sin(4t)$$

Therefore the right attempt would be

$$Y_p(t)~=~At + B + e^{2t}(Ct^3 + Dt^2 +Et +F) + G\sin(4t) + H\cos(4t) $$

But I do not know a way to compute the constants without derivate eight times.

Comment: Perhaps, I am in the wrong. The question asks for a "suitable form for the particular solution Y(t)" if we were to apply the method of undetermined coefficients. 

You are correct. I think taking eight derivatives would be an unreasonable work exercise.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. But I guess my approach should be right and respects all of the given functions.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 

A few question regarding your response:

Where does the B come from in your particular solution? In what part of the RHS is B supposed to be matching.

Likewise, why are there four coefficients attached to e^2t when we have repeated roots of 2 three times from the complimentary solution?

Comment: Try it on the equation $y''+y=x^2$ with the guess $Y_p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ and as contrast only with $Y_p(x)=Ax^2+Bx$. I cannot argue why the $C$ has to be there but you have to get it with you.

Comment: $2$ is a triple root, thus the term for $t^3e^{2t}$ gets an additional factor $t^3$, thus $t^3e^{2t}(Ct^3+Dt^2+Et+F)$.